# Tagging friends in status update with php

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

If you post a status update or share a link on facebook there is an option to tag your friends as being 'with you'. It's not the same as tagging them with @ symbols.

here is an example: http://www.facebook.com/karin.ohara.98/posts/111246132363889

It shows the person being with alison frasier

I'm trying to code this myself in php. It works for normal status updates.  First I get the friend list and then try to add a 'with' parameter. Using chrome web developer tools didn't give much info as to how facebook does this. Doesn't work

```
shuffle($friends);

        $with = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
        {
            if($i < count($friends))
                array_push($with, array("tag_uid" => $friends[$i]));
        }


        $fields = array('name'          => $status['title'],
                        'message'       => $status['message'],
                        'caption'       => $status['caption'],
                        'with' => json_encode($with)),
                        'description'   => $status['desc'],
                        'link'          => $url,
                        'picture'       => $status['img']);

        $result = HTTP_POST("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $account->id . "/feed?access_token=$access_token",  // full URL to query
```

Answer (score 0):

> First I get the friend list and then try to add a 'with' parameter.

There *is* no “with” parameter when *creating* a post.

To tag users as being with the poster you have to use the `tags` parameter – as it is *clearly* described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Note that you will also have to specify a place for this to work.